# How to Stream Facebook Videos in android?

Tags: android, facebook, video, video-streaming

I am getting facebook video url in this format:

```
http://video.ak.fbcdn.net//cfs-ak-ash4//v//439792//191//302138979861285_50471.mp4?oh=1f60e18870bfa40e844c385b5173126e&oe=4FA25B00&__gda__=1336040192_c327f9df6c01001a10b3842c7c72eca0
```

From reference [here](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/sample-streaming-video-mediaplayer-or-how-to-stream-video-from-url-in-android), the video url used was `http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp`
When i replace this url with above facebook video url, it doesnot work.
Is there any ways to stream facebook videos in android ??
Hoping for best answer !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way it worked for me ,for playing video from a website , but in this i am not playing a video from FB

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/
                           watchv=JxYSlkh1Src&feature=player_embedded"));
                 startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: I am talking about facebook videos but not youtube.  
I had already tried facebook videos in action view but it doesnot work